# When will the thread resume running after it has called sleep() or Sleep()?

Tags: c, linux, windows

As per the linux programmer's manual, which says:
"sleep() makes the calling thread sleep until seconds seconds have elapsed or a signal arrives which is not ignored."

I think a thread would not resume execution as soon as its sleep duration expires.It may wake up early or late，It's not determinated.Right？

Comment: I dont think it will wake up early. It may wake up a little late, depending on when it scheduled to run again.

Comment: @Haris  I find this material from ubuntu manuals.
"sleep() makes the calling thread sleep until seconds seconds have elapsed or a signal arrives which is not ignored." So, I think it may wake up early by a signal.

Comment: Signal, yes. By itself, No.

Comment: @sunshilong369 You are correct. A sleep() call may be interrupted by a signal. But that (and the documentation you are quoting) goes for POSIX/Linux systems. I do not know how sleep and signals work on Windows. Also, of course your thread may sleep for a bit longer depending on when it gets scheduled for execution, but it shouldn't make much difference. If you want to resume sleeping in case of a signal, you can use [nanosleep()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html)  - again, documentation applies to POSIX

Comment: If not "molested" by a signal, `sleep` will guarantee the minimum amount of it's argument (i.e. if you specify 5, the wait will be _at least_ 5 seconds, and due to scheduling delay, a millisecond or so more).

Comment: @ Craig Estey @kyriakosSt Assuming that all the cpu resouces are ocupied by theads with higher  priority，the thread which has called `sleep` may have to wait for a long long time to resume running again if theads  with higher priority do not yield the cpu resouces.Am i right?

Comment: @sunshilong369: If you assume each task has a state that is one of "sleeping", "ready to run" (waiting for a CPU) and "running" (actually using a CPU now); then a change in state from "sleeping" to "ready to run" means that you're not sleeping anymore (even though you're not running either). In that case, "sleep is guaranteed to sleep for at least the requested time but may sleep longer due to things like timer IRQ jitter and timer precision; and sleep is guaranteed not to return for at least the requested time but may not return for longer due to things like scheduling".

Comment: @kyriakosSt, instead of signals, Windows has thread alerts, kernel asynchronous procedure calls (APCs), and user APCs. `Sleep` is implemented with a non-alterable `NtDelayExecution` call, which in the kernel is implemented via  [`KeDelayExecutionThread`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-kedelayexecutionthread) with `WaitMode = UserMode` and `Alertable = FALSE`. Since it's a user-mode wait and non-alertable, `Sleep` cannot be interrupted by either thread alerts or user APCs. The thread can be woken by a kernel APC, but it resumes sleeping automatically.

Comment: `SleepEx` enables the use of an alertable wait, in which case the `NtDelayExecution` system call may return early with either `STATUS_ALERTED` or `STATUS_USER_APC`. The implementation of `SleepEx` just resumes the sleep in the case of `STATUS_ALERTED`, since the Windows API doesn't use thread alerts. For `STATUS_USER_APC`, it returns early with `WAIT_IO_COMPLETION`. The latter name may be misleading. The user APC may have been from `QueueUserAPC` instead of I/O completion.

Comment: @Brendan  Maybe，there is **a simple clerical error** in your comment(" and sleep is guaranteed not to return for at least the requested time **but may not return for longer due to things like scheduling**").

Comment: @sunshilong369: Ah - you're right. Should be "might not return for longer" to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @Brendan You misunderstand me.I think it should be "but **may return for longer** due to things like scheduling".Remove "not".Because i think the schedule policy could cause the thread which have called `sleep` waits for cpu resources for a long time.

Comment: @sunshilong369: Oh, then that doesn't make sense to me - "it may return (to user-space), for longer"?

Comment: @Brendan It may take longer time to return to user-space.Am i right?

Comment: @sunshilong369 Due to scheduling policies and availability of resources, any ANY function call that waits/blocks waiting some resource may take an indefinite amount of time to return, if this is what you are asking. Your program cannot force the kernel to resume from sleeping at exactly, let's say, 3 seconds. But usually, your execution will resume after 3 + <something negligible> seconds.

Comment: @kyriakosSt  Thank you for the clarification. The change in state from "sleeping" to "ready to run" means that you're not sleeping anymore (even though you're not running either). Regardless of the signals which aforementioned, what the kernel could guarantee is that the thread stay in the "sleeping" state for some time which is exactly, let's say, 3 seconds.Not the duaration from "sleeping" to "running(ocuppy the cpu)".How long it would take from the state "ready to run" to "running" is not certain. Could I think in this way?Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, threads don’t wake up early (unless as aforementioned there is a signal to the kernel from a separate thread indicating that it should do so). 
In most kernels, the time argument of a sleep function is interpreted into a number of SysTicks. The task then reports to the kernel that it doesn’t think it will need compute time for at least that many ticks - so it is excluded from process queuing until the SysTick register is greater than (value at time of call) + (time argument). 
Typically, in a preemptive kernel that isn’t bogged down, a sleep call will last the desired time + 1 SysTick +- 1 SysTick (so anywhere from on time to a wee bit late). 
That is, at least, in the embedded world. All the timing goes mushy when you transition to x86.

Comment: What do you mean by "Typically, in a preemptive kernel that isn’t bogged down, a sleep call will last the desired time + 1 SysTick +- 1 SysTick (so anywhere from on time to a wee bit late). " Is there some clerical error（+ 1 SysTick +- 1 SysTick）?

Comment: What do you mean by "All the timing goes mushy when you transition to x86.".Why?Could you make it clear to me?

Comment: By 1 SysTick +1 +/-1, What I mean to say is that in my experience sleep calls will last at least the desired time plus anywhere from 0 to 2 ticks. Keep in mind on an average laptop, a tick happens about once every millisecond, so when delay is measured in seconds such jitter is negligible.

Comment: Yea,i see.Thank you for classification.

Comment: Also, x86 is not inherently a non-determinant architecture - it just tends to be that most operating systems written for it are not ‘hard’ real-time. Linux, for example, utilizes niceness to schedule tasks, often setting tens of threads to the same priority. A hard real-time kernel like TI-RTOS, on the other hand, explicitly prioritizes threads with only one task per priority level. If two threads of differing importance are ready to run, a ‘hard’ real-time OS guarantees minimum latency for the higher priority thread, whereas a soft real-time kernel might not.

Comment: I am developing applications with RTOS right now.  **I wonder that why x86 is not inherently a non-determinant architecture**.  Could you make it clear to me? You see, there are many kinds of RTOS could run on the x86 architecture, for instance, rtai, vxwroks, qnx, etc.

Comment: x86 isn't inherently non-determinant as a given set of consecutive instructions will always take the same number of clocks / time. This is inherent of the layout of transistors on the chip. I correlate x86 to non-determinant systems as the majority of x86 implementations utilize a non-hard-real-time OS, making the execution of tasks in the user-space non-determinant.

Comment: *determinate (adj.), not determinant (math fn) (facepalm)

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification.What would happen if calls the related api to put the thread to sleep in RTOS? When will the thread resume running?Is there any difference(compare to none real time OS)?

Answer (score 0):

As per the linux programmer's manual, which says " Furthermore, after the sleep completes, there may still be a delay before the CPU becomes free to once again execute the  calling thread.".

**So the time is not determined.**

Comment: Yea, i agree with you.